# Get matrix from plot and subplot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, subplot, imshow

I already had some figure that I saved before, Like this:

[image]

Now after some days, I need the original size of these images for copy these in my paper. I want to extract the main matrix of these three image for save these again with `imwrite` function.

I searched this problem on the internet but the people says I have to use `getframe` and `frame2im` functions. But how? I want the original matrix. Can anyone tell me how to extract the main matrix from the figured image in matlab??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
imgs = findobj(gcf,'Type','image');
images = cell(1,numel(imgs));
for i = 1:numel(imgs)
    images = get(imgs(i),'CData');
end
```

The image matrices should now be stored in the separate cells of `images`.